# Gnome gaming performance

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I have installed different linux distros with different DE's. What I've noticed is that gnome and specifically Ubuntu has smoother animation performance in League of Legends. I've installed KDE on Ubuntu also and didn't perform the same. All the distros have the same nvidia drivers and i used lutris to install the game. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: I can't give you a full answer on this, but I definitely have noticed too that anything graphical seems to play the nicest with gnome. I think part of it may have to do with just how other graphical applications play nicely with the GUI since it does seem to be the most established GUI on linux, but I truthfully don't know how valid that is or if that is even true. What kind of performance delta (difference) are you seeing between the two GUIs in terms of framerate?

Comment: It's not the framerate, it just feels smoother when i move the screen in game. On other DE's it feels like it's skipping frames and it gives you the impression that it's kind of laggy. The only game i noticed that was on League of Legends. I noticed on Counter Strike:GO that sometimes it freezes for a second and then it comes back but not on Gnome. On Gnome runs smoothly.

Comment: That's stuttering then, hmm, if you have the same graphics driver on both, it really shouldn't affect it. What GPU do you have specifically?

Comment: It's on the same workstation that i have different distros installed and different DE's. The GPU is GTX1070

Comment: Sorry, should've asked this in the last comment I made too, what nvidia driver version are you trying to run? Also, are you using multiple monitors?

Comment: 396 and 410(latest) Nvidia Drivers Lenovo AIO Y910 single monitor.